# Run azure webjob as singleton, with deployment slots

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-deployment

I have a website with a bunch of webjobs. The webjobs are continuous, but use Quartz.net to schedule internally. I'm using deployment slots to deploy my site to a staging site, which I then swap into production.

All works well, but I want to stop my webjobs from ever scaling out with my web app (i.e. not participate in auto-scale).

Now, I know I can create a `settings.job` file and set `{ "is_singleton": true }` ... BUT ... in my testing, that breaks my deployments to my staging site - what happens when I deploy is that on my staging slot they all become stopped (presumably because my settings.job file prevents them from running). If I remove the settings.job file and deploy to my staging site again, this doesn't happen - they remain running.

How do I stop my webjobs from scaling out with auto-scale, without breaking the deployment slot swapping strategy?

Thanks

Comment: Setting is_singleton to true is the way to do this. I'm not sure I understand how deployment slots and swapping slots is applicable here though since a slot is essentially just another site. Are trying to prevent scaling in a staging slot but allow it in a production slot?

Comment: I set `is_singleton`, and all my production web jobs are running.. If I then deploy to my staging site, all my web jobs (deployed with my web site), are set to stopped after deployment. If I remove `is_singleton`, then when I deploy to my staging site, my web jobs are deployed as started (which is what I want)

Comment: `is_singleton` to only for continuous WebJobs, so I don't think what you are experiencing has anything to do with it (unless you actually mean continuous WebJobs).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: *I want to stop my webjobs from ever scaling out with my website*

Comment: Are you using continuous or triggered web jobs?

Comment: I'm actually using continuous webjobs (which make use Quartz.net to run processes at various intervals). Updated the main question for clarity, hopefully

Comment: What makes you think that settings "is_singleton" is stopping all your web jobs and that you don't have one instance somewhere which is running it?

Answer (score 2):

I re-tested my deployment with a `settings.job` file with `is_singleton` set, and it worked correctly - the WebJobs deployed successfully and was running after the deployment had finished.

I'm not sure why this wasn't the case before - either something changed with Kudo, or perhaps I was confusing things by deploying my WebJobs inconsistently, but in any case, I can report this is no longer an issue :)